# Don't select text in QTableWidget cell when editing

Tags: pyqt5

My app allows double-clicking on a QTableWidget cell to edit the content. However, when I double-click on a cell, the existing content is selected.

How can I allow a cell's content to be edited without having the existing text automatically selected?

Answer (score 2):

Qt item views automatically call `selectAll()` when an editor is created and it's a QLineEdit or a Q[Double]SpinBox.

Since the call to `selectAll()` is done *after* the editor is created, a simple solution would be to connect to the [`selectionChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#selectionChanged) signal and deselect the text automatically. This can be done in an item delegate that would just override [`createEditor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#createEditor).

Note that this *must* be done only once, otherwise any user selection would become impossible. This also means that the signal must be disconnected *immediately*, and *before* deselecting (otherwise the function would be called again).

```py
class NoSelectDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = super().createEditor(parent, option, index)
        if isinstance(editor, (QLineEdit, QSpinBox, QDoubleSpinBox)):
            def deselect():
                # Important! First disconnect, otherwise editor.deselect()
                # will call again this function
                editor.selectionChanged.disconnect(deselect)
                editor.deselect()
            editor.selectionChanged.connect(deselect)
        return editor


# ...

table.setItemDelegate(NoSelectDelegate(table))
```