# How can I position the cursor where the mouse is clicked when editing a QTableWidget cell?

Tags: pyqt5

My app allows double-clicking on a QTableWidget cell to edit the content, but the cursor is always placed at the end of the existing content.

I've arranged for the content [not to be selected on edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72790705/dont-select-text-in-qtablewidget-cell-when-editing). How can I go about positioning the edit cursor where the mouse was clicked?

Comment: Maybe, inside that same function (after deselecting), set the cursor position based on [`cursorPositionAt()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#cursorPositionAt), by mapping the global cursor position to the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to place the insertion point at the location where you clicked in the grid cell. There are a few things you need to put in the right place, as noted below. This uses a `QTableView` control instead of a `QTableWidget`. I'm not sure how much will translate across.

```py
import PySide2.QtWidgets as qtw
import PySide2.QtGui as qgui

from PySide2.QtCore import Qt

# place the cursor where the mouse was clicked in a cell
# based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/72792962 and a comment
# from @musicamanta at https://stackoverflow.com/q/73346426
class ClickPositionDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    # override the createEditor behavior so we can capture the 
    # first `selectAll` that occurs automatically after the
    # QLineEdit control is created.
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = super().createEditor(parent, option, index)
        # set margins so text in the control aligns with the grid (optional)
        editor.setTextMargins(4, 2, 2, 4)

        if isinstance(editor, qtw.QLineEdit):

            def position_cursor():
                # Catch the initial selectAll event via the selectionChanged 
                # signal; this ensures the position is calculated after the
                # control is placed on screen, so cursorPositionAt will work
                # correctly.

                # Disconnect so setCursorPosition won't call this func again
                editor.selectionChanged.disconnect(deselect)
                # Get cursor position within the editor's coordinate system
                gpos = qgui.QCursor.pos()
                lpos = editor.mapFromGlobal(gpos)
                editor.setCursorPosition(editor.cursorPositionAt(lpos))

            # queue up the positioning function if and only if we got here 
            # via a simple mouse click (left mouse button is currently down
            # with no modifiers)
            if (
                qgui.QGuiApplication.mouseButtons() == Qt.LeftButton
                and qgui.QGuiApplication.keyboardModifiers() == Qt.NoModifier
            ):
                editor.selectionChanged.connect(position_cursor)

        return editor

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self):
        # Call the parent class's constructor
        super().__init__()

        ...

        # Create the data table
        self.table = QTableView(self)
        table_view = self.table

        # start editing as soon as a cell is selected (no need for Enter 
        # or double-click)
        self.table.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.AllEditTriggers)
        # or self.table.setEditTriggers(QTableView.CurrentChanged)

        # call our special delegate to position the cursor correctly when
        # clicking on a cell
        self.table.setItemDelegate(ClickPositionDelegate(self.table))

        # Set the central widget of the main window
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

        ...

        # be sure to run self.table.setModel(some_model) at some point
        ...


app = QApplication()
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: There are some issues: 1. `disconnect` will raise an exception, because you changed the function name (`position_cursor`) from the original answer; 2. QApplication inherits from QGuiApplication, so just use that (it obviously works anyway, but it's about consistency); 3. it will crash if the editor is a spinbox since QAbstractSpinBox (nor its inherited classes) doesn't have `setTextMargins()`; 4. the button/modifier check only works for `CurrentChanged` and `DoubleClicked` triggers, but not for `SelectedClicked`; 5. the imports are inconsistent with class names; 6. it's "musicamant**e**" :-P