# QTableView click to set insertion point in cell without selecting whole cell

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, pyside2

I'm trying out using a `QTableView` with `PySide2` in Python. The `__init__` method for my `MainWindow(QMainWindow)` class has the code below, which allows me to click on a cell once and begin editing. However, whenever I click on a cell, all the text in the cell is selected, and I have to click again to place the insertion point where I want or select a subsection of the text.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

        # Create the data table
        self.table = QTableView(self)

        # start editing with one click, instead of double-clicking to
        # activate the grid cell
        self.table.setEditTriggers(QTableView.CurrentChanged)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
```

Is there any way to click once to place the insertion point directly at a specific spot in the cell? e.g., if a cell said "insert here" and I clicked once between the "r" and "t", that would place the cursor like this: `inser|t here`.

Comment: See the post marked for duplicate and use `cursorPositionAt()` as said in [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73346426).

Comment: Thanks, those posts are helpful but don't really spell out a complete solution. In particular, `cursorPositionAt()` always seems to report the current cursor position (0 before the deselect, end of string after the deselect), so it doesn't seem usable for finding the desired cursor position.

Comment: Neither of these was a great match, since they use `QTableWidget` instead of `QTableView` and they don't actually have complete answers. But the "[related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73346426)" is closer to a duplicate of this, so I've posted a [working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74695863/3830997) there.

Comment: QTableWidget *IS* a QTableView (see the header of [its documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html), which lists it in the "Inherits:" section), so it **is** a match. The difference is that QTableWidget has its own internal model and adds direct functions to access it. This is explained in the [Model/View Programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) guide, specifically in the [Convenience classes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#item-view-convenience-classes) section.